# Rails 4 validation error with has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have troubles creating the records in an association with rails 4. It's basically an association between Entry and Author, with a join table in the middle called AuthorsEntry. The schema is the following:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :from, presence: true
  validates :to, presence: true

  belongs_to :event
  has_many :authors, through: :authors_entry
  has_many :authors_entry

class AuthorsEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :author, presence: true
  validates :entry, presence: true

  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :entry
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :entries, through: :authors_entry
  has_many :authors_entry

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :event, presence: true
end
```

In my `program_entries_controller.rb` I have the following methods:

```
 def create
    @program_entry = Entry.new(program_entry_params)

    author_ids_params.each do |id|
      @program_entry.authors << AuthorsEntry.build(author_id: id)
    end

    @program_entry.event = @event

    if @program_entry.save
      flash[:notice] = t(:program_entry_created_successfully)
      redirect_to organizer_event_program_entry_path(@event, @program_entry)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

def program_entry_params
    params.require(:program_entry).permit(
      :name, :abstract, :'from(1i)', :'from(2i)', :'from(3i)',
      :'from(4i)', :'from(5i)', :'to(1i)', :'to(2i)', :'to(3i)', :'to(4i)',
      :'to(5i)'
    )
end

def author_ids_params
  params.require(:program_entry).permit(:author_ids => [])
end
```

I already have the authors saved in my database, the create action should just add a new record for the Entry model and the association (authors_entry) table. But when I try saving the entry it always returns "is_invalid" over authors_entry.

Comment: Why do you repeat  `validates :name, presence: true` three times?

Comment: Whoops! Typo, I'll fix immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The join table should be named `AuthorEntries` to follow rails convention.